# Backtracking with state

Tags: haskell

The list monad provides an excellent abstraction for backtracking in
search problems. However, the problem I am facing now is one which
involves state in addition to backtracking. (It also involves
constraints related to previous choices made in the search path, but I
will attack that issue later.)

The following simplified example illustrates the problematics. The
function `sumTo` is given a nonnegative integer and a list with pairs
of integers. The first element in each pair is a positive integer, the
second element is the number of such integers available. The search
problem is to express the first argument using the integers in the
list, with count constraints. For example, here the integer 8 is
represented in different ways as sums of five `1`s, three `2`s and two
`4`s with the contraint that all numbers making up the sum have to be
even (so the `1`s can not be used).

```
λ> sumTo 8 [(1,5), (4,2), (2,3)]
[[4,4],[4,2,2],[2,2,4],[2,4,2]]
```

The following is my current recursive solution to the problem.

```
sumTo :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
sumTo = go []
  where
    go :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
    go _ 0 _ = [[]] -- base case: success
    go _ _ [] = [] -- base case: out of options, failure 
    -- recursion step: use the first option if it has counts left and
    -- is suitable; append to this cases where current option is not
    -- used at this point
    go prevOpts n (opt@(val,cnt):opts) =
      (if cnt > 0 && val <= n && even val
       then map (val:) $ go [] (n - val) $ (val,cnt-1):(prevOpts ++ opts)
       else [])
      ++ go (opt:prevOpts) n opts
```

While the function seems to work ok, it is *much* more complicated
than one without state, employing the list monad.

```
sumToN :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
sumToN 0 _ = [[]]
sumToN n opts = do
  val <- opts
  guard $ val <= n
  guard $ even val
  map (val:) $ sumToN (n - val) opts
```

Not having constraints, this one gives one additional solution.

```
λ> sumToN 8 [1, 4, 2]
[[4,4],[4,2,2],[2,4,2],[2,2,4],[2,2,2,2]]
```

Now I am wondering **if some higher order abstraction, such as
`StateT` or something similar, could be utilized to simplify the case
of backtracking with this kind of state constraints**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two versions below, the first that just uses lists, and the second with `StateT`.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
```

The list type is the type of *nondeterministic computations*.

Given a set of elements (given in compact form as a list of `(element, nb_copies)`), we can `pick` any one, and return it together with the updated set. The result is a pair `(Int, [(Int, Int)])`. As a regular function, `pick` returns all possible results of that action.

Internally, we can also follow the definition with an "imperative" point of view. If the list is empty, there is nothing to pick (the empty list is the failing computation). Otherwise, there is at least one element `x` (implicitly, `i > 0`). Then we either pick one `x` (`pickx`), or we pick one element from the rest (`pickxs`), being careful to put `x` back at the end.

```
pick :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, [(Int, Int)])]
pick [] = []
pick ((x, i) : xs) = pickx ++ pickxs
  where
    pickx = if i == 1 then [ (x, xs) ] else [ (x, (x, i-1) : xs) ]
    pickxs = do
      (x', xs') <- pick xs
      return (x', (x, i) : xs')
```

Then `sumTo` is defined as follows: if `n = 0` then the only solution is the empty sum (`[]`) and we return it. Otherwise, we pick one element `i` from the set, check its validity, and recursively look for a solution for `n-i` with the updated set.

```
sumTo :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
sumTo = go
  where
    go 0 _ = return []
    go n xs = do
      (i, xs') <- pick xs
      guard $ i <= n
      guard $ even i
      s' <- go (n-i) xs'
      return (i : s')
```

Now threading the set around can be tedious. `StateT` transforms a type of computation to be stateful. `[]` is nondeterministic computation. `StateT s []` is stateful nondeterministic computation, with state type `s`. Here the state will be the set of remaining elements.

Interestingly, `pick` can directly be interpreted as such a stateful computation. The intuition is that executing `pickState` removes an element from the state, which updates the state, and returns that element. `pickState` automatically fails if there are no more elements.

```
pickState :: StateT [(Int, Int)] [] Int
pickState = StateT pick
```

Then we repeatedly pick elements until we reach `0`.

```
sumToState :: Int -> StateT [(Int, Int)] [] [Int]
sumToState = go
  where
    go 0 = return []
    go n = do
      i <- pickState
      guard $ i <= n
      guard $ even i
      s' <- go (n-i)
      return (i : s')
```

---

```
main = do
  let n = 8
      xs = [(1, 5), (4, 2), (2, 3)]
  print $ sumTo n xs
  print $ evalStateT (sumToState n) xs
```

([full source](http://lpaste.net/362142))

Comment: `go 0 = return []` is subsumed by the other case. With `lens`, `pick = map (experiment $ \((k,i):xs) -> (k, [(k,i-1) | i > 1] ++ xs)) . init . contexts`

Comment: The other case always returns a list of at least one element though...?

Comment: No, `guard $ i <= 0` always fails. (Except if there are nonpositive coins, and on that sort of input one should be able to use those coins last.)

Comment: If the guard fails it doesn't return anything, not even the empty list.

Comment: I just removed `go 0 = return []` and I see `[]`.

Comment: You are, of course, right. I confused base success with base failure. Should these comments be removed to not confuse others, or kept around to warn them?

Comment: It's fine to leave this here because it may be instructive for people.

Comment: This is a complete answer to the question, even providing a link between two clear but different solutions: lists only and with state. Thanks a lot! (Functional thinking still has not stuck to me sufficiently: I was unable to see this solution even though I have implemented, e.g., `StateT`-based parsers. Also, my response was delayed because of a nasty case of flu I am having.)

Answer (score 4):

It's not much work to add the `StateT` monad transformer to your clean solution. You just need to add a layer of wrapping and unwrapping to lift the values into the `StateT` type, and then take them back out using [`evalStateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:evalStateT).

Your code would also benefit from internally using a more specialized type for the `opts` than `[(Int, Int)]`. [`MultiSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html#t:MultiSet) would be a good choice since it automatically manages occurrences.

Here's a tested example of what it could look like:

```
import Control.Monad.State (StateT, evalStateT, get, modify, lift, guard)
import Data.MultiSet (MultiSet, fromOccurList, distinctElems, delete)

sumToN :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
sumToN nStart optsStart =
    evalStateT (go nStart) (fromOccurList optsStart)
  where
    go :: Int -> StateT (MultiSet Int) [] [Int]
    go 0 = return []
    go n = do
        val <- lift . distinctElems =<< get
        guard (val <= n && even val)
        modify (delete val)
        (val:) <$> go (n - val)
```

```
λ> sumToN 8 [(1,5), (4,2), (2,3)]
[[2,2,4],[2,4,2],[4,2,2],[4,4]]
```

---

And actually, the `StateT` isn't benefiting us very much here. You could refactor it to take the `MultiSet Int` as a parameter and it would work just as well.

```
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.MultiSet (fromOccurList, distinctElems, delete)

sumToN :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
sumToN nStart optsStart =
    go nStart (fromOccurList optsStart)
  where
    go 0 _    = return []
    go n opts = do
        val <- distinctElems opts
        guard (val <= n && even val)
        (val:) <$> go (n - val) (delete val opts)
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. My real-life problem, from which I have simplified the example above, employs a number of different constraints, not only count constraints that fit `MultiSet` perfectly. However, `MultiSet` might still be beneficial for the part involving counts. Thanks!